# Does a thread still perceives the constructor's effect as happening after a volatile reference is set to reference the newly created object?

Tags: java, multithreading

I read it [here](http://www.periodicooficial.oaxaca.gob.mx/files/2011/05/EXT02-2011-05-19.pdf)-

> When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B
>   reads that same variable, the values of all variables that were
>   visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible
>   to B after reading the volatile variable. So from a memory visibility
>   perspective, writing a volatile variable is like exiting a
>   synchronized block and reading a volatile variable is like entering a
>   synchronized block

The below snippet is taken from [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html) and the article dates back to year 2001 when the semantics of volatile keyword were different.

```
class SomeClass {
  private Resource resource = null;
  public Resource getResource() {
    if (resource == null) {
      synchronized {
        if (resource == null) 
          resource = new Resource();
      }
    }
    return resource;
  }
}
```

The Double Checked locking is fixed if the reference is made volatile.

```
private volatile Resource resource = null;
```

But do I need to make the **member fields of the Resource class as volatile too** to ensure thread safety?

EDIT:

The author mentions in the same article that - 
Volatile doesn't mean what you think, either

> A commonly suggested nonfix is to declare the resource field of
>   SomeClass as volatile. However, while the JMM prevents writes to
>   volatile variables from being reordered with respect to one another
>   and ensures that they are flushed to main memory immediately, it still
>   permits reads and writes of volatile variables to be reordered with
>   respect to nonvolatile reads and writes. That means -- unless all
>   Resource fields are volatile as well -- thread B can still perceive
>   the constructor's effect as happening after resource is set to
>   reference the newly created Resource.

That means the **Double Checked Locking was fine prior to JDK 5, considering 
Resource fields are volatile as well or the class itself is immutable**. 
Please suggest.

Comment: You're mixing questions here. The double check lock makes certain only one object gets created, *and* only synchronizes if the object doesn't exist. If resource is volatile, that doesn't mean it's fields are, and you might want to declare them volatile also depending on how it is being modified.

Comment: It is almost never correct to use both `synchronized` and `volatile` for controlling access to the same object.  In the above case, you *could* get by with `volatile`, but since the logic is more than just a single access to a field, `synchronized` is more appropriate.

Comment: Where does it say DCL is fixed if you make the reference volatile? It appears you are drawing a different conclusion than the linked article.

Comment: The article dates back to 2001. With change in volatile semantics, its fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some old JVM's dated back to year 2001, the meaning of `volatile` keyword was sometimes misunderstood, so the implementation wasn't functioning like it should - this is the reason behind the statements in the second quote in your question, the one from article from 2001 - that a volatile is a nonfix to DCL.

a quote from: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_java_5.shtml

> As of Java 5, accessing a volatile variable creates a memory barrier:
>   it effectively synchronizes all cached copies of variables with main
>   memory, just as entering or exiting a synchronized block that
>   synchronizes on a given object. Generally, this doesn't have a big
>   impact on the programmer, although it does occasionally make volatile
>   a good option for safe object publication. The infamous double-checked
>   locking antipattern actually becomes valid in Java 5 if the reference
>   is declared volatile.

With Java 5 things has changed and write/read to `volatile` field can't be reordered with nonvolatile read/writes, so everything that in your code is stated to happen before the write to volatile really executes before this write. According to your snippet: If the member fields of the `Resource` class are immutable you don't need to make them `volatile` to make them safe to be read by other threads. If other threads (other than the one that constructs and initializes the fields of `Resource` instance) can modify these memeber fields then you need to make them thread safe (eg. marking them as `volatile` - this is just example of simple memory barrier, may not be sufficient). Considering your example with the change to use `volatile`:

```
class SomeClass {
  private volatile Resource resource = null;
  public Resource getResource() {
    if (resource == null) {
      synchronized {
        if (resource == null) 
          resource = new Resource();
      }
    }
    return resource;
  }
}
```

The `Resource()` constructor is fully executed before the instance is assigned to the volatile field. Reading threads will see all the memory that was written by the thread creating the instance - so all the intialization is visible, this means the publication of `resource` instance is thread safe.

**To be clear:**

> **The statement made by @BrianGoetz in the article from the 2001 that marking a field as volatile...**
>
> ...still permits reads and writes of volatile variables to be reordered
>   with respect to nonvolatile reads and write`s
>
> **doesn't hold anymore in modern JVMs (JVM >= Java5)**

**DISCLAIMER**
Often we use the term **memory berrier** when we speak about synchronization, but many sources states that it is really the reordering of instructions that is prevented by such barriers, so a typical **memory barrier** just assures that everything in the code that was stated to be executed before the memory barrier point (eg. entering synchronized block, writing volatile variable) was really executed before your program reach the **memory barrier** point (for eg. you know that if you read the reference to a volatile variable, it is not published before the constructor really finishes and return form initialization). There are **no flushes to the main memory** for synchronization - the CPU cache is written to main memory with other occasions, the thing that makes the memory visible to other threads in multi core CPU is **cache coherency hardware**

Comment: Why do they call the Double Checked locking as fixed then?

Comment: Because without `volatile` keyword it was possible that some other thread could read the `resource` in inconsistent state. Simply speaking without the volatile, a thread reading this variable may not see all the initializtion writes in to the `resource` made by the synchronized block, because other thread can see the `resource` reference updated (as not null), but can then read some stale values from fields from the inside of the `resource` instance. `volatile` makes all the writes made during initialization visble to all the reading threads.

Comment: I understand it very well that volatile will force to flush the state to the main memory. Even after making the reference volatile, why do they call the Double checked locking as fixed when it is not, considering the case when one of the instance variable declared in the Resource could be non-volatile.

Comment: It is fixed considering that the `Resource` class itself is a thread safe class. In case `Resource` is not thread safe you need to make it thread safe, and it don't have anything to do with the double check initialization - the 'Resource' is a separate class that needs their own thread safety in accesing or modifying their fields. In the case some thread in constructing a class and then publish it thru a volatile reference then all the initilaiztion writes are visible to other threads reading that field - it is just safe publication.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari on which page of "Java concurrency in practice" have you found the second statement? As it is clearly not compatible with the first one.

Comment: I am referring to the article and not to the book. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html

Comment: Yes, this article is from year 2001, the book is from 2006, in 2001 some of the JVM could not properly implement the JMM, things has changed since then. @BrianGoetz has already mentioned in this article that the volatile DCL trick works only on some year 2001 JVM's, but now it works on all JVM's.